# How do I include a newline in a text message sent as email from an ASP.Net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sms

I have an ASP.Net Application that sends text messages to mobile phones.  It does this by sending an email.  For instance, if your phone number is 555-555-5555 and your wireless carrier is Verizon, you can send an email to 5555555555@vtext.com and it will show up as a text message.

I want to be able to include a newline in the body of the message.  How do I do this?  Also please note that my ASP.Net program gets the message from a database (MS SQL Server) so what I really need to know is what characters to include in the message body when I store it in my database.

I already tried \n but it just showed up in the text message as \n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are building the bodies yourself prior to storage, the easiest way is to just use stringbuilder when building your strings and us `.AppendLine(stuff);` for each line

you can also use Environment.NewLine

Comment: That's so simple that now I feel silly for asking... I had tried something like that as well, but was faked out by the fact that SQL Server Management Studio just shows whitespace where the NewLine is, making me think it was stripped out.

Anyway, +1 to all the answers

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n`

That has worked for me in the past, so it's the first thing I'd try if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you need just a line feed, or a carriage return/line feed, so try using `CHAR`, like this:

```
insert into Messages
(PhoneNo, Message)
values
('123-555-1234', 'line 1' + char(13) + char(10) + 'line 2')
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe for SMS a linefeed is sufficient.  From C#, you can use `(char)10`.